# E-commerce Transactions in Google Analytics and in Google BigQuery for a Specific Product Brand

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Again, I am facing some discrepancies between data in Google Analytics and BigQuery, this time for E-commerce Transactions for a specific product brand. The query that I am using is this one:

```
SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(hits.transaction.transactionId) AS trans
FROM [data]
WHERE  hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = STRING(6)
AND hits.product.productBrand CONTAINS "product-brand-name"
```

For example, the number of transactions in GA is 7.200 and on GBQ is 4.700.

However, if I calculate the results without the filter above, this time they match both in GA and GBQ:

```
SELECT EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(hits.transaction.transactionId) AS trans
FROM [data]
WHERE  hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = STRING(6)
```

What am I doing wrong in the first case?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I am sorry but I don't see how it applies to my question, though. I just wanted to know why the query above does not give the correct results... why is it off-topic?

Comment: @SilviaPina Do you know what Flatten means in BQ? Could be web ui auto flattening yielding you the larger number?

Comment: I tried to use NEST() to avoid that, but I am still getting the same results...

Comment: @SilviaPina I think you need to unflatten your results in the web ui and write to a destination table.

Comment: Why is this required? I should be able to get the results through the web ui...

Comment: And how do I do it? Can you please show me?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. It might give you answers that you seek:

```
SELECT 
  hits.product.productBrand
  , COUNT(DISTINCT hits.transaction.transactionId, 10000) AS trans
FROM [data]
WHERE  
 hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = STRING(6)
AND 
 hits.product.productBrand CONTAINS "product-brand-name"
GROUP EACH BY hits.product.productBrand
```